# Is there a way using swagger to auto generate the error responses for APIs developed using SAP CAP

Tags: swagger, openapi, sap-cap

I have included `cds-swagger-ui-express` within my application to auto-generate the openAPI documentation as well as host it from the server itself. I was looking for a way to auto-generate the error response documentation by swagger itself. Below is my code with the existing document that is generated

```js
// srv/todo-service.js

const cds = require("@sap/cds");
const uuid = require("uuid");

module.exports = cds.service.impl(async function () {
  const { Todos } = this.entities;

  this.on("GET", Todos, async (req) => {
    try {
      if (req?._queryOptions?.err) {
        throw new Error("something happened !");
      }
      return todos;
    } catch (e) {
      throw {
        status: 403,
        message: e.message,
        originalError: e,
      };
    }
  });
});
```

```
// srv/todo-service.cds

namespace my.todoapp;

using my.todoapp as todos from './todo-service';

entity Todos {
  key id   : String;
  title    : String;
  completed: Boolean;
}

service ToDoService {
  entity Todos as projection on todos.Todos;
}
```

```js
// srv/server.js
const cds = require("@sap/cds");
module.exports = cds.server;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  const cds_swagger = require("cds-swagger-ui-express");
  cds.on("bootstrap", (app) =>
    app.use(
      cds_swagger({
        basePath: "/$api-docs", // the root path to mount the middleware on
        diagram: true, // whether to render the YUML diagram
      })
    )
  );
}
```

And below is the openAPI response doc generated by swagger
[image: openAPI response doc]

The error response structure that is documented here does not match with the error response that is returned by the API controller.